# python calling custom exceptions from if-statement and try-except

Tags: python, exception, if-statement, error-handling, custom-exceptions

So, I've created a custom exception that I want to call in 2 different ways (a if/else statement, and a try/except statement). Here is the custom exception:

```
class CustomException(Exception):   
   def __init__(self, value=None, *args, **kwargs):
     self.parameter = value
     for key, value in kwargs.items():
         setattr(self, key, value)

     for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
         print "%s => %s" % ( key, value ) 

   def __str__(self):
     return repr(self.parameter)
```

Here is how I am wanting to implement the custom exception:

```
try:
   if something:
       #make an error
       ;lsdfj
   else:
       raise CustomException('this is my custom message', file='somefile.txt', var2='something')
except Exception, e:
   raise CustomException(e)
```

My issues, I believe, are two fold:

1: When the standard `NameError` that is thrown in the `try/except` block (due to `;lsdfj`), I want to pass `CustomExceptions` some extra parameters like 'file', just like the `if/else` implementation; how would I do that?

2: When the custom exception is raised (from the if/else statement being false), the CustomExceptions class ends up being called twice, because I raise it in the if/else block then it gets raised again within the `except:` section.  I don't know how to get around this.

So, in the above case, I want to call CustomException when the `if-statement` is not true, and I want to call it when there is a standard exception thrown inside the code block... but currently, `if something:` evaluates to false then the `CustomException` will be raised twice...

So I want the custom exception to be used unilaterally throughout my code for `if/else` conditions, and standard python exceptions...

I know this explanation was convoluted but I'm not sure how else to explain what I'm after... Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order not to raise the exception twice, you should wrap the `try/except` block around the `if` statemnt only, like so:

```
if something:
   try:
       #make an error
       ;fdsfas
    except Exception, e:
        raise CustomException(e.message, file='somefile.txt', var2='something')
else:
    raise CustomException('this is my custom message', file='somefile.txt', var2='something')
```

And in order to pass the custom exception some parameters you must provide that parameters to the constructor of the class just like you did in the `if/else` statement.

Comment: Haha, don't get me wrong, I'm not a fan of complication for the sake of complication, I am just worried that there may be circumstances where I need to have the try/except outside of the if/else, in which case I'm back at square one... right?

Comment: Unless you expect the condition to fail (for example `if 5 is equal to 5` will raise an invalid syntax error because `equal` is not a keyword in python) there is nothing to worry about. The code in the `if` branch is wrapped in the `try/except`, so it can't go wrong, and the `else` has got only 1 line so it can't go wrong.

Comment: while I'm liking this solution more and more, I am experiencing the same issue as the other solution that was posted where I receive the exception traceback after my CustomException class runs for the if/else error thrown... how can I prevent the traceback from happening on the outer block?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please expand on that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27902/discussion-between-sadmicrowave-and-ionut-hulub)

Answer (score 3):

You could in the `except` block use:

`if not isinstance(e, CustomException): raise CustomException(e)`

**Edit:**

A `sys.exc_info()` before the `raise` inside the `except` will successfully remove the traceback to the source of the exception i.e. `NameError`.

Comment: so, if I use this solution I also get the exception traceback when the exception is thrown due to the `NameError`which I am trying to avoid... (the custom exception thrown during the if/else statement works fine). Any way to keep the traceback from showing?

Comment: The original traceback from `NameError` seems to be suppressed but I am still getting the traceback from the `CustomException` raise event...

Comment: I'm afraid for that you will have to use [`sys.excepthook`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) and send it a custom tailored `traceback instance`.

Comment: Where should I print the `traceback`, at bottom level or at the highest level af the call? @Bleeding Fingers